# Spring boot app logs not showing in eclipse/SpringSTS on macOS High Sierra

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I recently updated to macOS High Sierra OSX10.13 after that my STS was not showing logs only the logo shown in image.
I tried same thing on Eclipse Mars but same output.

[image: Logs Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/196

The workaround is to disable either the ANSI output in the console or in the launch config of the boot app.

STS 3.9.1 will do that automatically on macOS High Sierra.